# How to handle a C++ header file with a extern call to C function and a class object

Tags: c++, c, cross-language

I am trying to compile an application involving both C and C++ files. With one particular header I face issues. The file in question (a C++ header file), would look something like this:

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#include "MyCCPObject.h"

int foo1(int);
int foo2(int);
int fooObject(MyCCPObject myCppObject); // Function involves a Class "MyCCPObject" type

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    int foo3(void); // Function called in a C file
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //TASK_H
```

I have a function `fooObject()` which has a `MyCCPObject` class type as a parameter. Also, one of the functions, `foo3()` would be called from a C file. 
When the C compiler, compiles this header, I get the following error:  `"error: #20:identifier "class" is undefined"`. To avoid this, I had to:

1. Place the `fooObject()` declaration within compiler guards:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
int fooObject(MyCCPObject myCppObject);
#endif
```

2. Place compiler guards also in the class declaration in the header file `MyCCPObject.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class MyCCPObject
{
public:
    MyCCPObject(uint32_t val);
private:
    uint32_t value;

};
#endif
```

Note: The `MyCCPObject` would not be called in any C file.
So, what would be a better approach, when I have a C++ header file, which involves:

1. Function would involves a class object
2. A `extern` call to a C file

Comment: Can you list all the file names with their contents?

Comment: Well, when the whole application is being compiled, the C compiler throws errors about ´"identifier "class" is undefined´, since the header file is included the C file due to the ´extern´ call. To avoid this, I had used compiler guards. Now am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: @Phalgun In my case, the `task.h` is the include file in question. The `task.cpp` file would the compiled file, but a couple of methods, like the `fooObject(MyCCPObject)`, and it would also use objects of type `MyCCPObject`. Next comes the C file, some `App.c`, wherein the function `foo3()` would be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The makers of C++ wrote a [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq) which is also giving some guidance on [how to mix C and C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp). They are also looking at the possibility to [use C++ objects from C code](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#cpp-objs-passed-to-c).

**Option 1**: If you just want the C compiler to be able to parse your task.h header file, then you could hide the C++ parts my using `#ifdef __cplusplus`:

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include "MyCCPObject.h"

int foo1(int);
int foo2(int);
int fooObject(MyCCPObject myCppObject); // Function involves a Class "MyCCPObject" type

extern "C" {
#endif
    int foo3(void); // Function called in a C file
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //TASK_H
```

**Option 2**: If you want to make the `fooObject` function accessible from C, then you can change MyCppObject.h to provide the full class information to C++ and only a minimal `typedef` for C. The `typedef` makes sure that C understands just the class name `MyCCPObject` without writing `class` or `struct` before it.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class MyCCPObject
{
public:
    MyCCPObject(uint32_t val);
private:
    uint32_t value;

};
#else
typedef struct MyCCPObject MyCCPObject;
#endif
```

and task.h to

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#include "MyCCPObject.h"

int foo1(int);
int foo2(int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    int fooObject(MyCCPObject *myCppObject); // Function involves a Class "MyCCPObject" type
    int foo3(void); // Function called in a C file
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //TASK_H
```

Please note that I needed to change the signature of `fooObject` to take a pointer to the object as the C code does not see the complete class and does not know the size of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Use separate headers for your C and C++ code.

Move the `foo3` declaration (including the `__cplusplus` guards) inside a separate header. Let's call it `Foo3.h`
You now have the following files:

- `Task.h` - contains the declarations for `foo1` and `foo2`, `fooObject` and includes `MyCCPObject.h`
- `Foo3.h` - contains the declarations for `foo3`
- `Task.cpp` - includes `Task.h` and `Foo3.h` and provides definitions for `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3`
- `App.c` - includes `Foo3.h` and uses `foo3`

From your build system (make, cmake etc.), when building the C++ library, add the files `Task.h`, `Foo3.h`, `Task.cpp` (and the other files related to `MyCCPObject`)

When building the C application, add only `Foo3.h` and `App.c`. That way, the other headers (which contain C++ code) will not be compiled and hence not give out any errors.